# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find', cache error

Tags: python, django, memcached

In my local environment the django development server works fine with no errors.

When I run the app on a production environment with nginx & gunicorn I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

This is the source of the error:

```
if cache.get('ratings').find(name_input) == -1:
    result = food.objects.get(name = name_input)
```

I have memcache imported:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
```

and in my settings.py:

```
CACHES = {
   'default': {
       'BACKEND':   
       'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

I expect the webpage to work without errors

--------EDIT:--------------

Providing more info I have a JSON script in my HTML section that sends the variable to python. 
Then python catches it.

I repeat that everything works like charm locally.

===================================

--------Edit new------
I have tried to change the location of memcache to point to my server in "settings.py":

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': 'MY_IP:11211',
}
```

}

but this attempt didn't work
I can print normally to the syslog, the values ARE NOT NULL

Comment: I should note that the problem isn;t fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was that I didn't have memcached installed in the first place; even though I used this command to install it:

```
pip3 install python-memcached
```

Then I used another command instead:

```
sudo apt install memcached
```

and everything works fine now :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `cache.get('ratings')` is unable to find the string 'ratings' so it returns NoneType by default, so it's unable to use the .find attribute.
You should try printing the cache to see if there is the string ratings inside it

Comment: i tried doing so, and none of the variables inside the cache get printed. I also get the same error

Comment: Is cache a dictionary?

Comment: You can check it's type by using `print(type(cache))`

Comment: I put the print statement in the top of the code -1 for test only containing print("@@@@") but nothing showed on the syslog ; it shows the same error with different timing only,

Comment: Usually when that happens in python it's because there's a problem before the print section

Comment: Try filling your code with prints to see if any of them get printed

Comment: There is no value on this key ```rating``` in your case (In *Memcached* DB). You are expecting ```str```, but it returns ```None```.

Comment: I printed the values in the syslog, and all of them showed fine -I printed the self.GET['value_key'] value-, non gave null or blank. does the memcache implementation differ between local environment -development environment- and publishing environment -on a real server-?